# Can 1 zone of a 3 zone mini split be capped of and use only 2 of the zones?

Tags: hvac

Can 1 zone of a 3 zone mini split be capped of and use only 2 zones of the system?

Comment: Do you not want to install it, or just not want to use it? The latter is trivial, just leave it turned off.

Comment: Tell us the model

Comment: It could create unwanted airflow constriction reducing overall air flow, you have to experiment with it

Answer (score 2):

That's not uncommon. Though it's unclear if this is a removal of an active zone or an install-time not installing one of 3 zones. In the latter case, you are better off (and will normally run more efficiently) getting a matched set, rather than repurposing one that's bigger than you need.

The load of the two heads should be in the range of the load of the compressor unit (so it's more commonly seen with a compressor that could run 3 smaller units running one smaller unit and one bigger unit, such that the load of the heads is more or less equal to the load the compressor can supply, not 2/3rds of it.) But since the outside unit can work with only one of the connected heads calling for cooling or heat, it can work with the mis-matched load - it's just not going to be quite as efficient as a matched unit.